# How to access a variable data in typescript, or javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I would suggest you see the code first and read this. I'm trying to access the data of eventClick that is in "options" object like shown in the code. the problem is if want to access the data outside of that variable I'm getting nothing. Can anyone suggest how to access that data in outside!

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedEvent: any[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {

      this.options = {
          plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin],
          header: {
              left: 'prev,next,today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,timeGridDay,listDay'
          },
          editable: true,
          eventClick: function(i) {
              return i.event.title
          },
      };
      console.log(this.options.eventClick);
  }
}
```

I'm expecting console should return value of that function.

Comment: The code you've posted is hard to read in its current form. Can you please fix the indentation?

Comment: Sure, you can copy the same code edit, however you like it.

Comment: "I expecting console should return the value of that function" ... https://jsfiddle.net/sLz8w6vt/ as you can see, it returns the value of the `eventClick` option, as it should. The value of the eventClick option is a function. So it prints the function definition. I'm not sure what you are expecting to happen? You can't **execute** the function this way. It makes no sense, because it would be out of context.

Comment: What you've done here is give the function definition to fullCalendar. When someone clicks on an event, fullCalendar will execute that function. At that moment, the `i` data exists in the scope of the function. Using `return` is no good, because you're returning the data to somewhere inside of fullCalendar's code. You can't access it there, and fullCalendar isn't interested in it, so it just gets lost.

Comment: If you want to use that `i` data outside the function, then it would make sense to call some other function from within that context, .e.g `eventClick: function(i) {
              someOtherFunction(i.event.title);
          }` maybe. You can define `function someOtherFunction(title) { ... }` elsewhere in your code. In that function you can do anything you like with the data provided. Clearly you cannot read the data from the eventClick function before it has happened, which is what you seem to be trying to do (although it's not 100% clear)?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
eventClick: (i) => i.event.title;
```

Comment: both will work my friend, it will return just a function if I console.log that value.

Comment: All you've done here is define the function a different way. I'm not sure how you think it's useful. Then again, the question is not very clearly defined either, so the best thing to do would be to seek clarification from the OP instead.